# Stupid mouse move coordinates in dart

Tags: dart

I am learning Dart and I was trying to make a very simple drageable HTML element. I followed patterns I'm used to from javascript but it doesn't work as expected.

When making drageable object from scratch you usually do the following:

1. Listen on mouse down event on that object
2. Upon mouse down, remember mouse coordinates relative to the object's top-left corner
3. Listen for any mouse movement. For every move operation, move the object to cursor location *minus* the coordinates you remembered earlier.
4. Upon any mouse up event, stop following mouse movement.

So I produced this code:

```
class DrageableControl {
  DivElement _elm;
  DrageableControl(String txt, int x, int y) {
    //Create element and set up styles
    var elm = this.setupElement(x, y);
    //Append element to document, add some text and start listeners
    document.body.append(elm);
    elm.text = txt;
    setupEvents();
  }
  //This function creates all event necessary for drag operations
  setupEvents() {
    Point relativeMouseOffset = null;
    _elm.onMouseDown.listen((MouseEvent e) {
      Rectangle myPos = _elm.getBoundingClientRect();
      relativeMouseOffset = new Point(e.offset.x-myPos.left, e.offset.y-myPos.top);
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    });
    //Of course this is completely wrong, the listener should only be added for the duration of dragging
    document.onMouseMove.listen((MouseEvent e) {
      if(relativeMouseOffset!=null) {
        print("Clicked at: ${relativeMouseOffset}\nCurrent mouse position:${e.offset}");
        _elm.style.top = "${(e.offset.y/*-relativeMouseOffset.y*/)}px";
        _elm.style.left = "${(e.offset.x/*-relativeMouseOffset.x*/)}px";
      }
    });

    document.onMouseUp.listen((MouseEvent e){
      relativeMouseOffset = null;
    });
  }



  setupElement(int x, int y) {

    var elm = this._elm = new DivElement();
    //TODO: Use css?
    elm.style.position = "absolute";
    elm.style.top = "${y}px";
    elm.style.left = "${x}px";
    elm.style.border = "1px solid red";
    elm.style.backgroundColor = "#FFAAAA";
    elm.style.cursor = "default";
    //elm.style.transition = "top 1s";
    return elm;
  }
}
```

Problem is, that some coordinates delivered by `MouseMove` are complete nonsense. See the console:

```
Clicked at: Point(-76.0, -143.0)
Current mouse position:Point(1, 1)
Clicked at: Point(-76.0, -143.0)
Current mouse position:Point(374, 272)
Clicked at: Point(-76.0, -143.0)
Current mouse position:Point(1, 0)
Clicked at: Point(-76.0, -143.0)
Current mouse position:Point(376, 273)
Clicked at: Point(-76.0, -143.0)
Current mouse position:Point(0, 1)
```

As you can see every second mouse move event delivers broken data - coordinates right around `[0, 0]`. So how can I filter out this invalid data? Why does it happen?

So far I'm probably fixing this by adding:

```
 if(e.offset.x+e.offset.y<5)
    return;
```

Comment: It's a while since I implemented drag-n-drop but I didn't use offset AFAIR. Have you tried `e.client.x`/`e.client.y` instead.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. The problem was caused because `MouseMove` event also bubbles and `offset` property holds the coordinates relative to the element that triggered the event. That's why I got those strange numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `e.client.x`/`e.client.y` instead.